# A Beautiful Looking Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, sequence

In the picture given below, can you find out which picture will take place of the question mark and add your reasoning as well?
 1.)
[image]   2.)[image] 3.) [image] 4.)[image] 5.)[image] 6.)[image] 7.)[image] 8.)[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The next symbol is

> [image]

Reasoning

> The symbols represent the planets: 
>  1.) Mercury: [image] 
>  2.) Venus: [image] 
>  3.) Earth: [image] 
>  4.) Mars: [image] 
>  5.) Jupiter: [image] 
>  6.) Saturn: [image] 
>  7.) Uranus: [image] 
>  8.) Neptune: [image]

Comment: why the simbols represent the planets?

Comment: @lois6b The symbols are in dependence on the roman gods which the planets are named after. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_symbols for more information